# Replace column values based on other column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, columnsorting

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Police | 1 |
| other | 0 |
| Ambulance | 0 |
| Police | 1 |
| other | 0 |
| Ambulance | 1 |
| Police | 1 |
| other | 1 |
| Ambulance | 1 |

Data entry error was detected in the data and I am required to correct it. If for any
claim transaction “Column A” is NOT “Police” and Column B == 1
Then Update “Column A” to Police.
Wherever I have "1" in "Column_B' I want the value "Column A" in Police

I tried this command

df.loc[(df['Column_A'] !="Police") & (df['Column_B']==1)]

From this command I'm only getting the dataframe but I want to replace the value to police in the same dataset without adding any new column or variable.
I want to acheive this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Police | 1 |
| other | 0 |
| Ambulance | 0 |
| Police | 1 |
| other | 0 |
| Police | 1 |
| Police | 1 |
| Police | 1 |
| Police | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

condition that Column A is not 'police' is not necessary.

```
df.loc[df['Column B'].eq(1), 'Column A'] = 'Police'
```

`df`

```
  Column A  Column B
0   Police      1
1   other       0
2   Ambulance   0
3   Police      1
4   other       0
5   Police      1
6   Police      1
7   Police      1
8   Police      1
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! It truly helped me